# Making elements appear/disappear with Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I need to make a make elements within a div appear and disappear when the div is clicked. When then webpage is loaded, it should just say "Click here". After clicking, new text saying "Click here again" should appear under the original text. After clicking again, new text appears under that saying "Click once more". After clicking again, all that text is deleted and new text saying "Thank you" appears. After clicking again, that text is deleted and new text saying "Goodbye" appears. After clicking once more, everything is deleted including the box that the text appears in. I am new to this and don't really know what I'm doing, and I can't even get an alert message to pop up when the div is clicked, which seems like it should be pretty simple. Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project4.css">
    <script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="project4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="main" class="box">
<p id="clickHere">Click here</p>
<p id="clickHereAgain">Click here again</p>
<p id="clickOnceMore">Click once more</p>
<p id="thankYou">Thank you</p>
<p id="goodbye">Goodbye</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My javascript code to just try to get an alert to pop up:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
  });
});
```

And my css code:

```
.box {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Prototype or jQuery?

Comment: My bad, I am using prototype. I got confused from trying to look around online and figure out how to do this. This is prototype.js https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3.0/prototype.js

Comment: That looks like jQuery code. For example, [`$(document).ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) is a jQuery thing, as opposed to Prototype's [`document.observe`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/observe/).

Comment: Here's a [demo with Prototype](https://jsfiddle.net/2ud41nfx/).

Comment: Ok thank you, I got confused and have been trying to use jquery stuff the whole time lol. I'm starting to make some progress now, I got the page to load with just the message "Click here" and can make it add the message "Click here again" after i click, but I don't know how to make it do something different for the second, third, fourth etc clicks. It just keeps adding "Click here again" every time I click.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, set a click observer for the div and all of its children:

```
$("div").observe('click', myHandler);
```

Then perform the show/hide operation in myHandler.

A working example:

```js
// array of paragraph ids to show/hide
const ids = ["clickHere", "clickHereAgain", "clickOnceMore",
  "thankYou", "goodbye"];
const idCount = ids.length;
let index = 0;

// add click listener to div
$("main").observe('click', myHandler);

// handle the click
function myHandler () {
  if (index >= idCount - 1) return;
  
  // hide the currently visible paragraph
  $(ids[index]).addClassName('hide');
  
  // show the next paragraph
  index++;
  $(ids[index]).removeClassName('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="main" class="box">
  <p id="clickHere">Click here</p>
  <p id="clickHereAgain" class="hide">Click here again</p>
  <p id="clickOnceMore" class="hide">Click once more</p>
  <p id="thankYou" class="hide">Thank you</p>
  <p id="goodbye" class="hide">Goodbye</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll point out that in this example the top code block `$('div')` points to the element with `id="div"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a raw solution for your problem in **jQuery**, you may just transfer the logic to `prototype.js`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // turn off your paragraphs and buttons
  $("#click2").hide();
  $("#click3").hide();
  $("#click4").hide();
  $("#button2").hide();
  $("#button3").hide();
  $("#button4").hide();

  // click the first button and hide and show the next
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("#click1").hide();
    $("#button1").hide();
    $("#button2").show();
    $("#click2").show();
  });

  // click the second button and hide and show      
  $("#button2").click(function() {
    $("#click2").hide();
    $("#button2").hide();
    $("#button3").show();
    $("#click3").show();
  });

  // then the third
  $("#button3").click(function() {
    $("#click3").hide();
    $("#button3").hide();
    $("#click4").show();
  });
});
```

And your HTML code:

```html
<p id="click1">This is paragraph 1</p>
<button id="button1">Click me</button>

<p id="click2">This is paragraph 2</p>
<button id="button2">Click me again</button>

<p id="click3">This is paragraph 3</p>
<button id="button3">Click me one more time</button>

<p id="click4">You are done clicking</p>
```

Not an elegant solution, but those are the basics of it, **jQuery** has a `toggle()` function, just in case you need to give the user the ability to show the paragraph again. replace `.show()` and `.hide()` with `.toggle()`